# setInterval and form submit

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get setInterval working while a file uploads.

My html:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='jimbo'>
   <input type="hidden" name="<?=ini_get('session.upload_progress.name'); ?>" value="myupload" />
   <input type="file" name="file1" />
   <input type="submit" id='submitme' />
</form>
```

Please **ignore the php session upload** part of this question, that is all functioning correctly.  My problem is with the jQuery.  I want the setInterval() to run **whilst** the form is uploading.  But  I cannot figure out how to write that in jQuery.  This is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jimbo").submit(function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajx.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#feedback").html(data + Math.random(999));
                }
            });
            //$("#feedback").html("hello " + Math.random(999));
        },500);
        //return false;
    });
});
```

If I leave `return false;` in there, i get the output but no file uploading.  If I remove it, I get  the file uploading but no output.  How can I have both ?

Comment: If you remove `return false` your browser should refresh?

Comment: on success of your ajax request , submit the form with jquery

Comment: @CodingAnt That doesnt work

Comment: @Chud37 what you tried can you share

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the browser is being redirected due to the form being submit before the file upload has completed. This is why the `return false` make things work - it prevents the form submission. Try hooking the event to a button click instead.

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='jimbo'>
   <input type="hidden" name="<?=ini_get('session.upload_progress.name'); ?>" value="myupload" />
   <input type="file" name="file1" />
   <input type="button" id='submitme' />
</form>
```

```js
$("#submitme").click(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajx.php",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#feedback").html(data + Math.random(999));
            }
        });
    }, 500);
    $('#jimbo').submit(); // submit the form manually
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting the same results :(

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#submitme").click(function () {

             var refreshId = setInterval( function() 
             {
                   $.ajax({
                    url: "ajx.php",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#feedback").html(data + Math.random(999));
                    }
                });

             }, 500);

          });
    });
```

Comment: @Chud37 As you mentioned you want to run setInterval while the form is uploading. Above code would do that.

Comment: @sajankumar - Have you tested this code? It doesnt work.  It has the same results.

Comment: @Chud37 after you got success response  it should work. I want you to check the response. Are you sure you got "success" function triggered ?

Comment: @sajankumar - Yes I used your code above as all the vars and filenames were the same, and I got the same result.